# Multi step prediction of a time serie using multiple inputs with LSTM

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, keras, lstm

I am new to deep learning and LSTM networks and I would like to know if they could be a good fit for my problem.
My reference example is this (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/keras-users/9GsDwkSdqBg/kV1Ep9E_BAAJ).
So I have information about a set of users (~500). For each of them I know, across a time period of 25 days, two scores: 1 and 2.

[image: Two time series trend]

My goal is to predict, in a given day *n* the score 1 for the next *d* days. (Please forget that the 2 trends seem correlated, as it is not a typical situation). From what I read about LSTM, the key part is to shape the data in the correct way.

My initial input, for every user is a vector of 50 values (25 scores 1 and 25 scores 2):

```
User 1: | SC1(1) | SC1(2) | SC1(3)| ... | SC1(25) | SC2(1) | SC2(2) | SC2(3) | ... | SC2(25) |
User 2: | SC1(1) | SC1(2) | SC1(3)| ... | SC1(25) | SC2(1) | SC2(2) | SC2(3) | ... | SC2(25) |
...
```

where *SC1(1)* indicates the score 1 at time point 1.
I would then split the data 90% to train the model and 10% to evaluate it.

So given my training set (450 samples), the input *X* and the target *y*, assuming that I want to look back in the past for 3 time points, and predict the next 3, would look like:

```
X:                                          Y:
|SC1(1)|SC1(2)|SC1(3)|SC2(1)|SC2(2)|SC2(3)|    |SC1(4)|SC1(5)|SC1(6)|
|SC1(2)|SC1(3)|SC1(4)|SC2(2)|SC2(3)|SC2(4)|    |SC1(5)|SC1(6)|SC1(7)|
|SC1(3)|SC1(4)|SC1(5)|SC2(3)|SC2(4)|SC2(5)|    |SC1(6)|SC1(7)|SC1(8)|
                  ...
|SC1(20)|SC1(21)|SC1(22)|SC2(22)|SC2(21)|SC2(20)|   |SC1(23)|SC1(24)|SC1(25)|
```

My questions now are:

**1)** Are the data split and arranged in a correct format (to be processed using Keras)?

**2)** Do I only have to look back as much as I want to predict forward? If not, is there a rule of thumb for those values?

**3)** Does it make sense to train a network on sequences of data that belongs to different users? (i.e *X* will be defined as the collection of all the possible sequences of 3 steps generated from all the users)